# Ant build: Some input files use or override a deprecated API

Tags: java, android, ant, build, release

While trying to build android application using the command prompt ant script.

```
ant release
```

getting below error.. I am sure it is something to do with the use of old deprecated api's.

```
facebook\internal\Utility.java:538: error: incompatible types: Object cannot
be converted to long
[javac]             bundle.putLong(key, (long) value);
[javac]                                        ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 4 errors
[javac] 3 warnings</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert

```
bundle.putLong(key, (long) value);
```

to

```
bundle.putLong(key, (Long) value);
```